# Running a java application in linux

Tags: java, linux, fedora

I am running a java application with mysql as back-end and i am using fedora operating system, now is there any way to run that application alone when that system boots up and also i want to disable all other unwanted services which is not required for the application to run. How do i achieve this ? Any tips and help would be useful

Answer (score 2):

In SysV-like distributions (like fedora), services are started at boot and stopped at shutdown by the [init.d](http://www.ghacks.net/2009/04/04/get-to-know-linux-the-etcinitd-directory/) system.

Answer (score 1):

Fedora FAQ: [How do I run something when the computer starts](http://www.fedorafaq.org/basics/#startonboot)?

Answer (score 1):

To set mysql service start with the system boot process, execute `chkconfig mysqld on` as root. You can refer the document below for more assistance:

[http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_:*Ch34*:_Basic_MySQL_Configuration#Starting_MySQL](http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_:_Ch34_:_Basic_MySQL_Configuration#Starting_MySQL)

To start the application on system startup, you can configure the script file as mentioned in the link below:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-how-to-run-a-command-when-boots-up.html

To find the running services and to manage them on start up, you can refer the link below:

http://www.fedorafaq.org/basics/#services

Answer (score 1):

To integrate Java apps into Linux's init.d system you may find http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/product-overview.html useful.